# sub menu have same width as top menu

Tags: css

I've the following menu struckture, but I can't make the last part act as I want.

When you hover over a menu item it shows the children, that part is fine. But when i hover, i would like the "blue" menu to have the same width as the entire red, and the blue text show me fixed to start from the left.'

Can anyone help me going, been trying to create this for an hour now.

thanks

```css
ul.nav {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

ul.nav>li>a {
  color: white;
  padding:20px;
  background-color: red;
}

ul.nav>li>ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
ul.nav>li>ul>li>{
  display:block;
}

ul.nav>li>ul>li>a {
  color: white;
}

ul.nav>li>a:hover~ul {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 1.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 2.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 3.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: no im not using jquery, look in the snippet

Comment: You could try `width: calc(100% + 200%);
    box-sizing: border-box;` and adjust the sum of that calculation according to the number of top-level menu items you have, since that will justify the overall length of the menu in question itself. It's not the most elegant method though and not so *dynamic*, so more a dirty hack. I'm sure someone can provide a better method that's more scalable.

Comment: **Bonus:** To keep your dropdown visible when hovering off the top-level menu item: `ul.nav>li>a:hover~ul, ul.nav>li:hover ul:hover {
    display: block;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this. I have given `position:relative` to `ul.nav` and `position:absolute;` to `ul.nav > li > ul` submenu. and I have added html tag `<div class="clear"></div>` to clear div beacause `ul` have `float:left` property. and also add some other css please check in code.

```css
ul.nav {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

ul.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

ul.nav>li>a {
  color: white;
  padding:20px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

ul.nav > li > ul {
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.nav>li>ul>li>{
  display:block;
}

ul.nav>li>ul>li>a {
  color: white;
}

ul.nav>li>a:hover~ul {
  display: block
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 1.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 2.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 3.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Edit your answer to explain what changes you've made to the code to achieve this result.

Comment: Wait a minute. I will explain it.

Comment: @TonyNielson It's my pleasure...:)

Comment: @MatthewBeckman hmm thanks. but it's my responsibility to explain my answer so people understand very well.

Comment: Right, but you didn't explain your answer, you just dumped a code snippet.

Comment: @MatthewBeckman now please see i have explain my code sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, i removed the `padding` in the submeny `ul` and added padding to `a`

```css
ul.nav {
list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    background: #00f;
}

ul.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

ul.nav>li>a {
  color: white;
  padding:20px;
  background-color: red;
}

ul.nav>li>ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
ul.nav>li>ul>li>{
  display:block;
}

ul.nav>li>ul>li>a {
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.nav>li:hover ul {
  display: block;
      padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 1.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 2.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 3.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As i said, I would like the blue Menu to be the same width as the Total red menu,